# Swift - How to pass variable that's an empty array to a function?

Tags: arrays, swift, parameters

I'm trying to pass a **variable** that's an empty array to a function. The following works:

```
if line == "" {
    buffer.lines.replaceObjects(in: lines, withObjectsFrom: [])
} else {
    buffer.lines.replaceObjects(in: lines, withObjectsFrom: [line])
}
```

But I can't pass a **variable** set to an empty array without a runtime error. The following doesn't work:

```
var emptyArray: [String]=[]
buffer.lines.replaceObjects(in: lines, withObjectsFrom: emptyArray)
```

Is there a way to do this in Swift?

Comment: What is the error that you get?

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Comment: You most likely are trying to pass the wrong type of array.  What is the signature of the `replaceObjects(in:withObjectsFrom:)` method?  What are the types of the inputs?

Comment: The method `func replaceObjects(in range: NSRange, withObjectsFrom otherArray: [Any])` needs a range as first parameter. Looks like you are developing an Xcode Source Editor Extension and in those `lines` is of type `[String]`.

Comment: What is the function supposed to do in case of an empty array ? If *Do not replace anything*  then the `if` block is pointless or if *remove the items* then use an appropriate API? And **never** check for an empty string with `== ""`. Use **always** optimized `isEmpty`

Comment: Yes, I'am working on a Xcode Source Editor Extension so you don't have to select the line before Cut/Copy the line. Every editor I've used since Brief in 1988 has had this feature. Drives me nuts that I have to first select the line. I just installed beta 5 an it now works. I was adding this question at a different computer so I didn't have the error message handy and now it's working. Passing an Array as [] deletes the range. I have one known bug left then final commit to GitHub @ github.com/mretondo/CutCopyUnselectedLine. Thanks for your fast responses, wasn't expecting that:)

Answer (score 0):

Problem fixed in Xcode 10 beta 5, I was using beta 2.